# How to include\run some number of PHP files with the same functions using classes

Tags: php

Let's imagine we have few PHP files:

test1.php

```
<?php
function test() { echo "Test 1"; }
test();
?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
function test() { echo "Test 2"; }
test();
?>
```

Some of function and variable names could be equal in these files.

Also, we have main PHP script, which need to run all of these sub-scripts:

```
<?php
include("test1.php");
include("test2.php");
?>
```

The problem is - functions\variables are previously declared.

Question: is there a way to run such number of PHP scripts from general PHP script ?
I'm not familiar with classes, but I feel solution is somewhere here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [namespaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) to solve this problem. Modify your include files to add a namespace declaration (for example for `test1.php`):

```php
<?php
namespace test1;

function test() { echo "Test 1\n"; }
?>
```

Then in your main PHP file:

```php
include("test1.php");
include("test2.php");

function test() { echo "Test 3\n"; }

// call the different test functions
test1\test();
test2\test();
test();
```

Output:

```
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```